# Provable Security: concrete approach vs asymptotic approach

Tags: cryptanalysis, provable-security

I was reading Professor Lindell and Katz's book. Their book takes the asymptotic approach to the security proof, while lots of papers on crypto seems to use the concrete approach when it comes to security proof.

Are there any references/books that use the concrete approach in their proofs?

Comment: This seems like a perfect example of a nicely asked question that's currently off-topic as an open-ended reference request, but *could be* a candidate for a canonical Community Wiki Q&A depending on the outcome of the ongoing [poll on reference request policy](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/919) at Meta. I'd encourage anybody with opinions on whether or not questions like this one should be considered on-topic here to read the meta thread and possibly vote on it.

Comment: Just to be sure: is it correct to assume you're referring to the book "Introduction to Modern Cryptography"?

Comment: Yes. Introduction to Modern Cryptography by Lindell and Katz